# Ajax call to php script returns 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm a WordPress designer, I developed a contact form for one of my themes that's validated via jQuery.

Please check the code below, then read the notes beneath.

```
$('.submitemail') .click(function() {

    //VALIDATION CODE GOES HERE

    if ( /*VALIDATED SUCCESSFULLY*/ ) {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: templatePath+'/lib/scripts/sendEmail.php',
            data: 'visitorname=' + visitorname + '&visitoremail=' + visitoremail + '&visitormessage=' + visitormessage,

            success: function(contactResults) {
                //SUCCESS CODE
            }

        });
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

- sendEmail.php is a correct script that sends email using PHPmailer class.
- templatePath variable has the value of the full template path which looks like this: http://somedomain.com/wp-content/themes/themename
- The jQuery code above is located in lib/scripts/jfunctions.js (same directory of the php script)
- The whole process (ajax and php) works perfectly as expected in many servers, (tested in two servers by me and other servers by my theme users).

**The Problem:**

In SOME servers, the success handler is not triggered while the ajax call to sendEmail.php is actually passed successfully and the php script is processed and email is sent.

When I check with firebug to see why the success handler is not triggered, firebug shows "not found 404 error", It's like a false alarm.

**Possible causes:**

I think some servers is configured to block such ajax calls.

What might be the cause for this weird issue? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

@nowk: sendEmail.php code is:

```
<?php 
// Code for loading WordPress environment goes here //

$themeName_optionTree = get_option('option_tree');

$name = trim($_POST['visitorname']);
$email = $_POST['visitoremail'];
$message = $_POST['visitormessage'];


$site_owners_email = $themeName_optionTree['owner_email'];
$site_owners_name = $themeName_optionTree['owner_name'];
$email_subject = $themeName_optionTree['email_subject'];
$success_message = '<p class="success-box">' . $themeName_optionTree['success_message'] . '</p>';

if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = 1; 
}

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = 1;    
}

if (strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error['message'] = 1;
}

if (!$error) {

    require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->Subject = $email_subject;
        $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->Send();
        echo $success_message;
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo '<p class="warning-box">' . $e->errorMessage() . '</p>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<p class="warning-box">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Please note that the above code executes perfectly even when ajax returns 404, weird huh!.

Comment: Can you add the code for the file receiving this ajax request?

Comment: An AJAX call should always have a response body. Some browsers get confused when the request is over but there's not data received. Just echo "OK" or "ERROR" or something at the end. Anything. Handy for debugging as well.

Comment: Rudie is completely right with that - there have been countless issues I could have avoided in the past if I had only returned some sort of data. Worst of all, I know many plugins and libraries rely on data being returned instead of the response code (malsup's form plugin for example). Always return at least a single character if you don't want to return structured XML/JSON. Also - any chance we can see this in action at some URL?

Comment: @Rudie, @Lev, Thanks. Actually there is a response message as you can see after $mail->Send(); there's echo $success_message; and it is returned, but it doesn't show up because the success handler of ajax fails after a 404 error. If this is not what you mean please let me know.

Comment: @mobi How right you are! And I see $success_message isn't empty. Using Firebug or Chrome Inspector (or another dev tool), can you see the entire response? There has to be an HTTP code and headers and (possibly) a body. Even if there is a (server) error. Share it with us? =)

Comment: @Rudie, please excuse my delays. Yes, using Firebug I can see the response which is "<p class="success-box">Your message has been sent.</p>"

Comment: Response headers are: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2011 15:38:49 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
X-Pingback: http:// www.somedomain.net/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: bb2_screener_=1303832329+41.218.19.88; path=/
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Apr 2011 15:38:49 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=50
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Request Headers: POST /wp-content/themes/themename/lib/scripts/sendEmail.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.somedomain.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16
Accept: */*
Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:115
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.somedomain.net/contact/
Content-Length:195
Cookie:REMOVED TO SHORTEN CHARACTERS
Pragma:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-cache

Comment: The HTTP response code is 404, but it does execute your script AND returns the right html?? `Woot!?` Then there must be something in the Wordpress code (?) that sends that 404... What you **could** do, is send a 200 yourself =) like this `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')` (before you send anything else!)

Comment: Alternatively, you could just ignore the HTTP response code and instead of `onSuccess` bind the response handler to `onComplete` (I think that's possible in jQuery by replacing "success" with "complete" in the ajax call). I'm **guessing** the responseText will be the same (your HTML). **I've created an answer, which is easier to read**

Comment: I also faced similar issue while using Spring MVC on Apache Tomcat 8.0. For some reason it was looking for a success.jsp file (HTTP Status 404 - /Assignment1/WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp) I created a blank success.jsp file and issue is fixed. Not sure what would be the logic behind it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since the server sends a 404 (for god knows what reason), there are two ways to fix/circumvent this:

1. Ignore the HTTP response code and change `success` to `complete` in the jQuery ajax call, so that the handler is executed when the request is done no matter the server response. You know the server response (it always works). The HTML should still be available in the jQuery `complete` handler.
2. Overwrite the 404 that something sends on the server (probably something Wordpress) by executing (**before printing any output**): `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')`. Since the script is executed, this will overwrite the crazy 404 and jQuery will receive that 200 and execute the `success` handler.

You could try both =) I'm pretty sure the first one will work (but that's not so clean). I'm also pretty sure the 2nd will work, but I don't know Wordpress well enough to make promises =)

Comment: you are the man! Thanks. Adding `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');` just before `echo $success_message;` did the trick, although I couldn't figure out where that 404 error comes from. The first suggestion for some reason caused the returned message not to be inserted into the page hence not showing up.

Comment: Thanks and I'm glad it works. The 404 is sent somewhere in Wordpress... Don't know Wordpress, so don't know why =)

Comment: template_redirect in WP sent 404 without any reason. Thanks man!

Comment: Adding `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');` still works for people having the same problem in 2014 :) This problem occured to me on a client's Godaddy server in a WordPress environment.

Comment: Would you include that on the main site or just the .php-file that ajax requested?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's because Wordpress already has an AJAX mechanism built in and it stops you from implementing it on your own. This page explains how to add AJAX to plugins:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Here's a snippet from the page:

---

### Ajax on the Administration Side

Since Ajax is already built into the core WordPress administration screens, adding more administration-side Ajax functionality to your plugin is fairly straightforward, and this section describes how to do it.

Here's a short example. All this will be in one file.

First, add some javascript that will trigger the AJAX request:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_action_javascript');

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Then, set up a PHP function that will handle that request:

```
<?php 

    add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

    function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

That's it! You will need to add a few details, such as error checking and verifying that the request came from the right place ( using check_ajax_referer() ), but hopefully the example above will be enough to get you started on your own administration-side Ajax plugin.
NOTE: Since Version 2.8, The javascript global variable ajaxurl can be used in case you want to separate your javascript code from php files into javascript only files. This is true on the administration side only.

Answer (score 2):

As seen here https://cooltrainer.org/fixing-false-404-headers-on-external-pages-including-wp-blog-header-php/ this solution tested and works well:

```
require_once("path/to/wp-config.php");
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request(); 
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals(); 
$wp->send_headers();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, in my case this is the only working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into the problem, you might check that the ajax request is actually going where you think it is going. There could be several things going on here, such as the server is set up to redirect any requests to /wp-content/ somewhere else.

Capture some header information using firebug, and perhaps livehttp headers.

Comment: Thanks @Cthos, using firebug, header information shows no problems URLs are correct.

Comment: When you're getting a 404, is it telling you some kind of redirect? Can you hit the page manually on problem servers?

Comment: no, there was no redirect, I get something like this: POST http: //www.somedomain.net/wp-content/themes/themename/lib/scripts/sendEmail.php STATUS 404 not found. URL is correct. When accessed directly, it also returns 404 (some times).

Comment: Then yeah, it sounds like the server is doing something crazy to you. If you have access to its conf files, I'd check for redirects in .htaccess, and make sure file permissions are set correctly.